# How to popup an Alertdialog every 2 hours?

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog

After login i want to show dialog using `AlertDialog` for every 2 hours.

Tried below code :

```
 private void ShowDialog() {

        new SweetAlertDialog(getContext())
                .setTitleText("Attention!")
                .setContentText("Have You Checked Followup list? Check Here !!")
                .setConfirmText("Followup List")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                           ShowFollowupList();
                        sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();

                    }
                })
                .setCancelButton("Cancel", new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Use `AlarmManager` .. Why showing alertdialog for every 2 hours?

Comment: Their is one list  which is continuously getting new data..so alert is for team to check updates.

Comment: This seems a defferable task which need not to be Exact . So you can go with `WorkManager` .. If you want it to be Exact then `AlarmManager` is the only solution .

Answer (score 1):

By using Work Manager you can display it.

Refer link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

**Schedule tasks with WorkManager**
API makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or device restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WorkManager` for Scheduling task in `background` and `foreground`

**Example for Periodic Request**

```
PeriodicWorkRequest request= new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerClass.class,
                            2, TimeUnit.HOURS).addTag("TAG").build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
```

**Create a worker class**

```
public class WorkerClass extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {

        // Do the work here

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

add this in `build.gradle`

> implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:2.1.0-alpha01'

check the latest release doc https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work

Comment: It depends on the app and its functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager` to achieve it.

First, create your Receiver class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` as below.

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // show your dialog here
    }
}
```

After that, create an `AlarmManager` and `PendingIntent` instance to set the alarm, as below.

```
public void setAlarm(Context context, int requestCode) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourReceiver.class);

    // different request code enable you to set alarm more than one
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final long everyTwoHours = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in milliseconds
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), everyTwoHours, pendingIntent);
}
```